# How to enable Bitlocker for C drive or any drive?

Tags: bitlocker

I am using following PowerShell script to enable BitLocker on C drive,

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "ABC123" -AsPlainText -Force
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -Password $SecureString

And getting the output,

cmdlet Enable-BitLocker at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
PasswordProtector:

I tried to pass parameters 
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -Password $SecureString -RecoveryKeyPath "\fileserver\keys" -RecoveryKeyProtector

but still, it's showing errors.

Can anyone have a running script to enable BitLocker?

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution for my question, script to configure BitLocker with password,

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "123456789" -AsPlainText -Force
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "D:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -PasswordProtector -Password $SecureString